# Count month between two dates and insert result into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

The following code working well on browser:

```
<?php

$start    = (new DateTime('2010-12-02'))->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = (new DateTime('2012-05-06'))->modify('first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) 

{

echo $dt->format("Y-m"). "<br>\n";  

}

?>
```

and give the following result on browser:

> 2010-12 2011-01 2011-02 2011-03 2011-04 2011-05 2011-06 2011-07
>   2011-08 2011-09 2011-10 2011-11 2011-12 2012-01 2012-02 2012-03
>   2012-04 2012-05

In phrunner i tried to insert the above data (**which is multiple data**) into one row in mysql but **only the first data** inserted (2010-12):

```
...
foreach ($period as $dt) 

{

$sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (payment) values ('".$data->format("Y-m")."')";
CustomQuery($sql);

}

?>
```

Comment: Probably related to `CustomQuery`...

Comment: shouldn't it be `.$dt->format("Y-m)` ?